# Vertically Centering Text: Label Tag Next to Big Font within Anchor Link

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, centering

I want to center text vertically and tried different solutions from the Stackoverflow board. (`vertical-align: middle`, `line-height`, Flexbox …)

But in my case from those I tried not a single one works. (For example, when using Flexbox the label on the right is not centered in the second line but centered between the first and second line.)

In this example the big anchor text on the left side (August) and the right side (Month) should be vertically aligned:

[image: Vertically Centering Text]

*Left side: Actual State (Month and label not really centered) • Right side: Desired Outcome*

Any ideas how to really vertically center a `span` tag next to bigger text within a link?

**Example Code**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwZmyz

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 48px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 280px;
}

.auto-suggest a {
  background: #eee;
  display: block;
  color: #666;
}

.auto-suggest li:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.auto-suggest-label {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  /* height: 100%; */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.auto-suggest [data-label="month"] {
  color: #5BBDC6;
}

.auto-suggest [data-label="season"] {
  color: #ffc54a;
}
```

```html
<ul class="auto-suggest">
  <li>
    <a href="#">August <span class="auto-suggest-label" data-label="month">Month</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Spring <span class="auto-suggest-label" data-label="season">Season</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Here two lines <span class="auto-suggest-label" data-label="season">Season</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: flexbox works fine... https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZGWGV

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Using Flexbox I found the same solution like you: _“(...) when using Flexbox the label on the right is not centered in the second line but centered between the first and second line.”_ But that's not what I am looking for. I made an image so you can see the desired outcome: http://i.imgur.com/1RIEZwj.jpg Any ideas how to get this?

Comment: Updated my pen https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/BZGWGV - will that work? Basically just align the text to the bottom, then move the right side text back up half + line height of the left text's font-size.

Comment: Thanks again, great approach! Unfortunately, it's still not working like intended: At list items which are two lines long the labels are now located at the lines’ end. On the contrary, one line list labels are placed just after the text. (This is how it should be.) I am looking for a solution which puts all labels (vertically centered) directly next to the main text, both at one _and_ two lines. http://i.imgur.com/1RIEZwj.jpg